# Social networks authorization and Android MVP

Tags: android, facebook, authorization, mvp

I decided to try the MVP pattern in Android app. And now faced with a problem. Where I need to initialize Facebook API etc like this:

```
FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
facebookCallbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
```

in presenters or in my views?

Yes, my presenters must know nothing about a Context, but how can I resolve this?

Can you show an example, please. My thanks.